# GA4 - How to view the list of items selected on "select_item" events

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I am adding Google Analytics 4 to my project, I have implemented in the products on my page, the "select_item" recommended event. In debug mode I can see that when a customer tries to see the product the event triggers and I see in the "items" tab the data of the product that the customer is seeing, however, it is not possible to see in any report which are the products that the customers have selected. Does anyone know how I can generate a report with the list of products that customers have selected?

```
gtag("event", "select_item", {
    item_list_id: "selected_card",
    item_list_name: "Card Selected",
    items: [
        {
            item_name: $(this).data("gacardname"),
            item_brand: $(this).data("gacampaign"),
            item_category: $(this).data("gacellcode"),
            item_category2: $(this).data("gasource"),
            item_category3: $(this).data("gatitle"),
            item_category4: $(this).data("gaaction"),
            item_list_id: $(this).data("gacardname"),
            item_list_name: $(this).data("gacardname"),
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the results after the colon for Items do not appear in quotation marks - It should display like this:

```
item_name: '$(this).data("gacardname")',
item_brand: '$(this).data("gacampaign")',
```